# Esprima parser working examples

Tags: javascript, parsing

The basic usage of the parser is
`esprima.parse(code, options);`
Now how can i use loc option here for javascript code can any one please explain with an example or provide a resource very all the options are explained with examples

Answer (score 2):

```
esprima.parse('var x = 42', { loc: true });
```

The syntax tree format is documented, see http://esprima.org/doc/index.html#ast (also for further reference to Mozilla Reflect API).